# Azure Static web apps custom callback page

Tags: azure-static-web-app

As part the authentication to a swa you may receive an error, this error is passed back to `swa` via the callback page eg

`/.auth/login/<provider>/callback?error=<error>&error_description=<description>`

The error code and message are just displayed as `{ code: 401, message: "..." }` which is not very useful for end users.

I would like to be able to customise this page to make it more user friendly.

It's reported on as in issue on [github](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/598)

Does anyone have a workaround